# Java Unit Tests - Parallelization + Multiple Threads + Infinite times

Tags: java, junit, testng, load-testing

I have bunch of Java JUnit test classes that make REST calls to Elastic Search. I am trying to check what is the best way to orchestrate the test suite so it satisfies the following -

1. Run them infinitely with different input parameters [helps me to load test ElasticSearch and gather response time(s) and check on caching features of ES etc]
2. Run several of these test classes in parallel
3. Run them in a multi-threaded fashion

Note # I understand there are several different ways to achieve it, for example using JMeter etc. I am trying to see if this can be achieved programatically.

One idea is to create a test suite in TestNG with parallelism option enabled and setting a cron to invoke the Test suite every X number of minutes.[how can I change the thread count here?]

Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference between #2 and #3?

Comment: If I have 4 test classes with 5 methods each - I may want to run 3 of the 4 test classes in parallel (this is # 2). 
And I also want 3 of the 4 test classes run in 5 different threads (this is # 3). Essentially treating my 4 different classes as 20 (4 times 5 ) different ones due to multiple threads.

Comment: Whoever down voted it or voted to close it, if you don't have ideas....PLEASE!

Comment: to run something in parallel you need multiple threads

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following options:

1. Use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) (Java Microbenchmark Harness) to run your tests in multithreaded manner and get a number of metrics. There is [jmh-tutorial](https://github.com/guozheng/jmh-tutorial) sample project which will help you to get started
2. Use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) tool, it comes with [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler which seems to be something you're looking for as it is designed to run JUnit tests in parallel. Moreover you will be able to use all JMeter power of workload definition in terms of ramp-up, tear-down, time to hold the load, defining required requests per second rate and reporting. Check out [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide to learn how you can run your existing JUnit tests via JMeter